# Tiny fonts on a Windows Server 2016 Standard Chrome file open dialog

Tags: google-chrome, windows-explorer, windows-server-2016, scaling

I run an instance of Windows Server 2016 Standard inside a Hyper-V VM. All scaling, fonts and resolution looks fine across all apps, with 1 exception: Google Chrome's file browser dialog: the displayed files look TINY as you can see here:

[image]

In the screenshot above, the left side shows the file-open or "browse for files" dialog in Chrome, opened by clicking an `<input type='file'>` button. The font of the available files looks tiny. The right side is a standard windows explorer (on the same VM - not on my host) and the fonts are correct.

The version of Chrome running on the VM is 109.0.5414.120 (Official Build) (64-bit). On my host OS (Win11) I do run modified scaling, and occasionally I have to modify the properties of an EXE to allow the application to drive the scaling, but this problem is inside a VM in which all other apps and fonts look perfect.

Many windows apps allow this sort of thing to be solved by going into `Properties->Compatibility->Change high DPI setting` thusly:

[image]

...but I couldn't get to this either on the Chrome.exe nor the windows explorer exe. And in any case, everything in Chrome looks fine *except* for that file browser dialog.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you uninstall Chrome and reinstall?

Comment: harry, when I try to uninstall Chrome, I get the error `Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.` The path it shows at the top of the dialog exists and I tried to open up permissions up and down the path, still get the same error. Totally stuck.

Comment: See if `chkdsk` can fix something. If not, add an image for the Properties of the problem folder, Security tab. Also of the Advanced dialog.

Comment: I went into `Properties -> Security` and opened up permissions wide on a number of folders in the tree/chain, then rebooted. Still no luck. Haven't run chkdsk yet but I'm not sure how that can help with a permissions issue.